# Динамичное меню

Tags: html, javascript, css

Как создать динамичное меню наподобие: http://www.tinymce.com/

Comment: По ссылке тяжело сказать чего вы вообще хотите. Страница же доступна - проанализируйте её средствами любого браузер для начала. Появятся конкретные вопросы - задавайте.

Comment: Там в верху меню

Answer (score 3):

Если почитать большая часть вопросов на ХешКоде - это такой, простите, БРЕД!

> Как создать динамичное меню

Изучаете HTML+CSS для разметки страницы, и красивого оформления меню.

Далее изучаете, допустим, php+mysql если уж динамическое меню нужно, либо JS там тоже можно динамическое делать.

Но обычно Динамика представляет собой изменение, а конкретно именно динамику. т.е. вытянуть данные откуда-то и вставить куда-то. Обновлять их постоянно, либо пока требуется.

Вопрос задан некорректно.

На него можно ответить так:

> Ну как. Просто.

Comment: Может быть автор имеет ввиду, как сделать так чтобы при наведении менялся фон, а после наведения таким и становился?!

Хотя, сложно угадать что имел ввиду автор вопроса. :)

Comment: 2 @Angelina_Jo в вопросе вообще нет вопроса как такового.

Comment: @Shrek это уже стандартный диагноз, особенно у молодёжи. Даже страшно от того, что я начинаю к этому привыкать. :(

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы сделать такое же меню, как на указанном вами сайте, надо просто скопировать разметку и стили этого сайта. Они достаточно простые

```
<ul id="menu">
<li class="active"><a href="..."><span>First</span></a></li>
<li><a href="..."><span>Second</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

и

```
#menu li {
    float: left;
}
#menu a: hover, #menu.active a {
    color: black;
    text - decoration: none;
    background: #CCC;
}
#menu a {
    float: left;
    color: #0F5A91;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 34px;
    line-height: 34px;
}
#menu li a span {
    float: left;
    height: 34px;
    padding: 0 16px;
}
```

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/). Чтоб было красивее - наворачивать стили и картинки.